# RedirectToAction Not Working when Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version

I have a login form that my project routes to when the user is not authenticated.  Authentication is cached and checked on every action. If the user is not authenticated they are routed back to the login screen with a `routeUrl` passed through the Url.  If the user is not authenticated on the initial load the `routeUrl` is null and I use `RedirectToAction` to navigate to the initial post logged in page.

When debugging, my first pass I provide correct credentials and click login.  Stepping through I can verify that the line

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Client" });
```

is executed. But the debugger never hits my breakpoint set on the destination line of the Client/Home/Index controller. I wait and it eventually times out.

On my second pass with the debugger the authentication is cached and the project routes me straight to the Client/Home/Index with no issue.

When deployed this behavior is different. The whole login process takes about 90 seconds after the button click for something that shouldn't take more the 5 seconds.  I am trying to debug this but, as stated before, after my Login action authenticates and invokes the redirect, the redirect does not happen.  The browser just sits idle with the spinner spinning and I cannot properly debug.

Here is the code.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(model.ReturnUrl);

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");

        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });

        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

The `RedirectToLocal` function:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Client" });
}
```

My main Home Controller Index Action that works when redirecting to the same page if the user is already authenticated.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Client" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling Login() using ajax post. Then the RedirectToAction() will not work you need to return an URL and then use JavaScript to redirect to that location.

Comment: Thank you, but Login() is called using a Form POST on a submit button.